# C++ derived types must define static constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is there a way to force derived types to define a `static constexpr` in C++? I have a base class, and I want to force every derived class to define a `static const bool has_property`.

I tried doing this with CRTP (so that each derived class gets its own `static const`):

```
template <typename T, class MyClass>
struct Base {
    T data;
    static constexpr bool has_property;
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T, Derived<T> > {
    static constexpr bool has_property = false;
};
```

But the compiler complains that `Base::has_property` is not initialized.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want `static constexpr`(C++11) or `static const`(C++03)?

Comment: You are missing the type (presumably `bool`) of the `constexpr`.

Comment: @iammilind I want `static const`, and thought there was some benefit allowing you to initialize `static constexpr` in the definition. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could insert a `static_assert` into the constructor of `Base`:

```
template <typename T, class MyClass>
struct Base {
    T data;

    Base() {
        static_assert(std::is_same<
                        typename std::decay<
                          decltype(MyClass::has_property)
                        >::type, bool
                      >::value, 
                      "Must be a bool");
        static_assert(MyClass::has_property || true, 
                      "Must be constexpr");
    }
};
```

This check will only work when the derived class is instantiated, *and* the default constructor of `Base` is used. The `constexpr` check doesn't work in g++ 4.7 at the moment.

---

Alternatively, you could use a type traits instead of a `constexpr` static member, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct has_property;

template <typename T>
struct has_property<Derived<T>> : std::true_type {};

// use as: has_property<X>::value.
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm actually trying to force subtypes to define a static array of bools of a specified length (the bool in the question was just an illustration). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Oliver: Compare with `bool[n]` instead of `bool` then.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe adding has_property value to your base template parameters will work for you:

```
template <typename T, class MyClass, bool hasPropertyValue>
struct Base {
    T data;
    static constexpr bool has_property = hasPropertyValue;
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T, Derived<T>, false > {
};
```

[UPDATE1]
For arrays - instead of passing single bool value - pass struct containing values:

```
template <typename T, class MyClass, class MyClassPropertyValues>
struct Base {
    T data;
    static constexpr bool has_property[MyClassPropertyValues::length];
};
template <typename T, class MyClass, class MyClassPropertyValues>
constexpr bool Base<T, MyClass, MyClassPropertyValues>::
 has_property[MyClassPropertyValues::length] = MyClassPropertyValues::initValues;

struct DerivedPropertyValues {
   static constexpr size_t length = 3;
   static constexpr bool initValues[length];
};    
constexpr bool DerivedPropertyValues::initValues[length] = { true, false, true };

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T, Derived<T>, DerivedPropertyValues > {
};
```

Comment: Good idea, but I actually want an array of bools-- if I pass the array as a template parameter, do you think it's readable still?

Comment: Added update with array of properties. Struct containing array of bools is quite readable I believe...